# Postgres error while doing Chef 12 server backup restore

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

As part of Chef 12 migration, need to take backup of existing server and restoring it in newly created Chef 12 server.
Using the chef-server-ctl in-build [commands](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_server.html#backup-restore) "backup" and "restore".

While doing the restoration of Postgres db dump into new Chef server, execution throws multiple set of errors.

Please find log snippet, showing the errors

```
....
....

ERROR:  role "bifrost" already exists

ALTER ROLE

ERROR:  role "bifrost_ro" already exists

ALTER ROLE

....

....
ERROR:  database "opscode-pgsql" already exists

....

....

ERROR:  type "auth_any_permission" already exists

ALTER TYPE

ERROR:  type "auth_permission" already exists

ALTER TYPE

....

....

ERROR:  function "group_id" already exists with same argument types

ALTER FUNCTION

ERROR:  function "groups_for_actor" already exists with same argument types

ALTER FUNCTION

....

....

ERROR:  relation "object_acl_group" already exists

ALTER TABLE

....


ALTER TABLE

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "actor_acl_actor_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (target, authorizee, permission)=(1, 1, create) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY actor_acl_actor, line 1


.....
```

and so on.

Please clarify, are these errors can be safely ignored?

if not, how to solve these errors for a successful postgres db restoration?

Comment: `chef-server-ctl cleanse` before the restoration may help. See the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/server_backup_restore.html#restore) for more details.

Comment: I'm providing "-c" option while doing the restore. But still getting the errors.
`chef-server-ctl restore name_of_gzip_file_dump -c`

Comment: Chef server backup restore steps mentioned in Chef docs are out dated. As part of the new procedure, we no need to perform the Postgres DB restoration step.
We have drafted the new "Backup and Restoration" steps with help of Chef support and updated the same in Chef support ticket.

So please let me, how to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to restore on top of an existing Chef database schema which means all the roles and schema objects exist already. Either do the restore on to a blank database or use something like `pg_restore --clean`.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the Chef documentation for restoring and it uses 'psql' command. Does it have any similar command and option in "psql"?

Comment: AFAIK there is no one-click restore solution. You'll need to learn how Postgres works and how to operate it.

Comment: Ok. If I'm able to crack the successful restoration of Postgres db in Chef backend, i'll update this thread.

Comment: It's not that hard, just drop all the stuff in the database before you restore it.